# change the active menu position to another menu position dynamically using jquery?

Tags: jquery, menu, css-position

I have a five types of circle menu like home,aboutus,news,blog,contactus. The active menu in right side position and the rest of menus are semi circle style.

My thought is currently home menu is active its after clicking rest of menus for example i click the news menu this menu goes to home menu position and home menu come for the news menu position after reload the page.how can i do this and interchange the menu position dynamically?

Comment: Can you show your code? :)

Comment: Place the code in jfiddle

Comment: @GintasK  jsfiddle.net/hrRXH/2

Comment: @Gangadhar  jsfiddle.net/hrRXH/2